# How to solve this equation which is of Cauchy-Euler form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a second order ode in the Cauchy-Euler form. The problem is, the coefficients of differentials in the equation are arbitrary and are not known numbers. This leaves me with a problem of identifying the nature of  roots of its characteristic equation. How do I get around this?

Comment: So your equation is just $x^2y''(x)+axy'(x)+by(x)=0$? Then you have to consider all the cases that the solution of a quadratic equation can fall into.

Comment: Yea, exactly. Then, probably I should choose a solution that would satisfy my boundary conditions. Right?

Comment: What boundary conditions? And yes, you select the integration constants so that initial or boundary conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Boundary conditions are that y(a) and y(b) are zero. The dependent variable in my problem is basically transition probability which has to be zero at the boundaries.